# Google form uploaded files need to be grouped in one folder automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form that allows users to fill business details and then add JPG files at the end of the form. I need a Apps Script that:

1. Creates a folder in Drive. The name of the folder should be same as the input received in the second input field "Business Name".
2. Move all the file received in that responce to that folder.

I have tried:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1VXzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";  

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

But, this is not a complete solution as it re-creates the same folder everytime I run the script. If I can run this script on form submit then it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `subFolder` variable does not point to a folder but to an instance of the `DriveApp.FolderIterator` class. To get a folder, use `.next()`, like this:

```js
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);
```